# Source recommendation for makeindex templates

Tags: makeindex

Does anyone knows a good source including some style-files for makeindex? On the other side, I could do this small thing on my own, but I need some teaching in this case :-)

I'm just looking for a basic style (like the default one), with small letters (scriptsize) and dotted lines from the entry to the page, two <strike>rows</strike> columns (perhaps three, therefore, there should be an option for that).

Edit:{Sub-entries should start below with a small indent of maybe 5mm}

## Example

**A**

alpha...............1

ammon...............5

**B**

...

And so on.

Comment: Two rows? I don't understand, maybe you want to say _columns_. The [`imakeidx`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.pdf) package provides an option for number of _columns_ using `multicol` package.

Comment: of cause, two columns.. I just used the google translator for "zweispaltig" and it returned something about row. Maybe it was bugged. Nevertheless, thank you for your response. I will have a look :)

Comment: I don't know about other users, but with the coffee mug in my hand i am not quite in the mood to set up a document for testing. If a MWE would be already here with the question, the situation may differ however.

Comment: I really understand your point. But I'm only looking for a source for templates or a source to get in, to write my own in a short. This example is only an example, if someone wrote something similar and could distribute it. :)